# MMD Textures missing vertices after importing

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, rigging, import

i am using the MMD_tools plugin for Blender 2.83 and I am having difficulty with missing vertices of the textures after importing a .pmx file. See the below images for examples of this. I have seen similar problems online, but the solution is still not clear. Rendered in Cycles.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with the vertices in your models.

First, I would recommend **Removing Doubles** and **Recalculating Normals**.

Select all vertices, merge vertices by distance (M > By Distance or Right-Click > Merge Vertices > By Distance), and recalculate normals (F3 > "Recalculate Normals")

If that didn't work, try **Clearing Custom Split Normals Data**

Select all vertices, press F3 and search for (F3 > "Clear Custom Split Normals Data")

Let me know if this helps. :)